# VBScript: ADO disconnected RS with GROUP BY

Tags: t-sql, active-directory, ado

I need to run a query against Active Directory to identify all the unique (distinct) operating systems + service packs in the domain.  I can do that pretty easily via the ADsDSOObject provider and a SQL statement.  But I need to also tally up how many accounts for each distinct combination.  I can do this against a SQL Server or Oracle database very easily using COUNT(field) AS X and GROUP BY field.  But with an AD query I can't use GROUP BY (as far as I know), so I'm funneling the recordset into a new disconnected recordset, but how can I run a COUNT() and GROUP BY statement against that?  Is there a better way than this?

Comment: I'm guessing this can't be done using ADsDSOObject.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a SQL Server available you could insert into a temporary table and then have TSQL.  Not pretty but that is what I would try.

Answer (score 0):

If I had SQL Server available I wouldn't bother with a disconnected recordset.  Apparently the GROUP BY option is unavailable to ADO disconnected recordsets.